# How use same variable in C for different values

Tags: c

I am trying to make a simple code in C, but i cant use the same variable:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(){

    char a;

    printf("Type something\n");
    scanf("%c", &a);
    printf("%c", a);

    printf("\nType something else\n");
    scanf("%c", &a);

    printf("something else -> %c", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Any tips?

Comment: When you say, you "can't use the same variable" what exactly is the problem? As far as I can see this should work, assuming you include `"\n"` in every one of your `printf` statements.

Comment: What do you mean _I can't use the same variable_? Are there compiler errors? What are your inputs, and outputs?

Comment: here printf("something else -> %c", a); i don't get nothing, is like i cant use the variable again (sorry about my english)

Comment: You need to use `" %c"` in the format strings because `scanf()` leaves the newline in the input and the second `%c` doesn't skip white space (such as newlines) before reading a character.  It's a common problem; there's a simple fix.

Comment: ow! thats fix the problem!

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` will read your input character by character, for example:

---

You run the program, and type `ab` when it asks you for input, the output will be:

```
Type something
ab
a
Type something else
something else -> bPress any key to continue . . .
```

Note the `b` in last line.

---

If you type `a` then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the output will be:

```
Type something
a
a
Type something else
something else ->       // Note: there is a new line character here
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: thanks, i understand and fixed using what Jonathan Leffler says! ^^